# Using Edit fields of a WebView as EditText android

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext

I have a web page loading into my `WebView`. It contains a certain form with Edit fields. I want to use these edit fields as `EditText` in my app and use them further.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

here is my code:

```
  myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.gmail.com");
```

Comment: @MD thanks for the response. The web page Iam currently loading is `www.gmail.com`

Comment: then show one snap plz

Comment: @MD I cannot upload a screenshot as I dont have enough points. Its basically just a `WebView` that loads `www.gmail.com`

Comment: but u can't modify that one becoz it's loading gmail official. ya you want to change the theme and try

Comment: @MD I didnt get your point about changing the theme. Can you please elaborate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47394/discussion-between-m-d-and-user2625086)